# Elasticsearch lowercase filter still being applied when custom analyzer is explicitly not using it

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm basically trying to disable the lowercase filter to be able to do case sensitive matching on text fields. Following the index, and analyzer docs I create the following mapping without the lowercase filter:

**PUT** /my_index

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I enable fielddata so I can inspect the tokenization afterward

**PUT** my_index/_mapping/_doc

```
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

I test the custom analyzer to make sure it doesn't lowercase, as expected

**POST** /my_index/analyze

```
{
  "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
  "text": "Is this <b>déjà Vu</b>?"
}
```

which gets the following response

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Is",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "this",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "deja",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "Vu",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Great, things are not getting lowercased just like I wanted. So now I try inserting the same text and see what happens.

**POST** /my_index/_doc

```
{
  "my_field": "Is this <b>déjà Vu</b>?"
}
```

and try querying back for it

**POST** /my_index/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "my_field": "Is.*"
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [
    "my_field"
  ]
}
```

and get no hits. Now if I try lowercasing the regex, I get

**POST** /my_index/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "my_field": "is.*"
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [
    "my_field"
  ]
}
```

which returns

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6d6PP20BXDCQSINU0RC_",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "my_field": "Is this <b>déjà Vu</b>?"
        },
        "fields": {
          "my_field": [
            "b",
            "déjà",
            "is",
            "this",
            "vu"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So it seems to me like things are still getting lowercased somewhere since only the lowercase regex matches and the docvalues all come back lower cased. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start so far!!!

The only issue is that you're not applying your custom analyzer to your field. Change your mapping to this and it's going to get you further.

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true,
      "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"       <-- add this
    }
  }
}
```